# How to deploy predictionio on http instead of https

Tags: ubuntu, server, ubuntu-14.04, prediction, predictionio

I have setted up `PredictionIO` by `pio-start-all`, submitted test data and has build and train too.

Now I am deploying it all the things is going right but server is deploying on https instead of http. I am using ubuntu 14.04

Logs is here

> [WARN] [Utils] Your hostname, med-lap-008 resolves to a loopback
>   address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.35.97 instead (on interface eth0)
>   [WARN] [Utils] Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another
>   address [INFO] [Remoting] Starting remoting [INFO] [Remoting] Remoting
>   started; listening on addresses
>   :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.35.97:51753] [INFO]
>   [Engine] Using persisted model [INFO] [Engine] Custom-persisted model
>   detected for algorithm com.myapp.URAlgorithm [INFO] [URModel$] Created
>   dummy null model [INFO] [MasterActor] Undeploying any existing engine
>   instance at https://192.168.35.97:8001 [WARN] [MasterActor] Nothing at
>   https://192.168.35.97:8001 [INFO] [HttpListener] Bound to
>   /192.168.35.97:8001 [INFO] [MasterActor] Engine is deployed and
>   running. Engine API is live at https://192.168.35.97:8001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue for me. It seems that the https is hard-coded:
https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO/blob/833f4dd5d598f24a66e13c49a5a6d85a1d40a334/core/src/main/scala/io/prediction/workflow/CreateServer.scala#L296

So the solution is to use the variable `HttpOptions.allowUnsafeSSL`:
https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO/blob/833f4dd5d598f24a66e13c49a5a6d85a1d40a334/core/src/main/scala/io/prediction/workflow/CreateServer.scala#L301
But I don't find a way to override it.

Maybe the **very bad** solution is to change the call to the server:

> I used -k option with https:
>
> curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "user": "u1", "num": 4}' https://localhost:8000/queries.json
>
> https://groups.google.com/d/msg/predictionio-user/w0ajF_nlFnM/iG4akmeSBgAJ

The **good enough** option: install PredictionIO 0.9.5 which has still a http service.

EDIT: another **good** option: install the ActionML version, following this guide: https://github.com/actionml/cluster-setup/blob/master/predictionio-by-actionml.md

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I install PredictionIO 0.9.5? There is no options for installing previous version given on site.

Comment: I tried but struggle too much... So I went back to the `curl -k` option... I've subscribed to the following bug: https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO/issues/221#issuecomment-217492764. And I don't understand how to install ActionML instead of Salesforce, but that can be a solution too.

Comment: I have also searched for this and found that the Prediction.io is a salesforce company repository and one of the partner says actionml has created a new fork for predictionio. Do you know which is the best to use salesforce or actionml?

Comment: You should read the instructions here: https://github.com/actionml/cluster-setup/blob/master/predictionio-by-actionml.md. Also I've just noticed the «remove ~/.ivy2 directory», which explains why I had so much trouble on the second tryout. I'll test it again if I have some time next week.